# Convert text representing vector to vector

Tags: r, shiny

I'm currently reading in something like the following as a factor:

```
c("DESIRE_minref", "DESIREMA_5_minref")
```

It's being read from a CSV, but I need it to be represented in my Shiny app as an actual vector. Is there any way for R to parse this factor and recognize that it is the code for a vector?

Thank you!

Comment: It is a vector if you are extracting a column from a data.frame (assuming the column is not a list)

Comment: @akrun The code I listed above is actually one element within a column in my CSV. When it is being read back into the program, it is being read as a factor.

Comment: It is a `list` column.  so, You may need to loop it with `lapply` i.e. `lapply(yourdf$yourcolumn, yourfunction)`  Or use a `for` loop, i.e. `for(i in seq_len(nrow(yourdf))) yourdf$yourcolumn[i]` returns that as a vector.  Then, apply the function as you needed

Comment: I typically dislike the use of `eval` to solve formatting problems, but this works: `eval(parse(text='c("DESIRE_minref", "DESIREMA_5_minref")'))` (returns a `character` vector, length 2).

Comment: @Ryan The example you provided before editing your comment actually worked for me!